# Changing the value in list of Objects

Tags: python

How do I change value in the list of objects?

I have list with objects

```py
obj_list = [Obj1, Obj2]
```

My object looks like this:

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, move=None, path=None):
        self.move = move
        self.path = path
```

Each object can execute a move from list:

```py
available_moves = ["UP", "DOWN", "RIGHT", "LEFT"]
```

So each object have stored an information about *move*.

```py
string1 = obj1.move # up
string2 = obj2.move # down
```

I want to add these moves to their object path list. But it keeps adding both executed moves from obj1 and obj2.

I tried to add a move with for loop:

```py
for i in range(0, len(obj_list)):
   temp = obj_list[i]
   temp.path.append(temp.move)
```

Obj1 looks like this:

```py
Obj1.path = ["UP", "DOWN"]
```

It should look like this:

```py
Obj1.path = ["UP"] 
Obj2.path = ["DOWN"]
```

Any ideas how to add a move to path in list of object?

Comment: Why do you have the `temp.path.append(temp.move)` in a loop if you only want to do it to one object in the list?

Comment: @rdas Each obj in obj_list stores a information about move. Obj1. move = "up", Obj2.move = "down". So for every object in that list I want to add their moves to path list.

Comment: Add your complete code to the question instead of just snippets. Make sure the code in the question can be executed as-is to reproduce the issues you are facing.

Comment: You should probably encapsulate the path modifications inside your Node class to track the path for the object. For example: add a `move_to(self, move)` method that does `self.move = move` and `self.path.append(move)`.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

```
   temp = obj_list[i]
   temp.path.append(temp.move)
```

which essentially works out to this, during one execution:

```
   temp = obj1
   obj1.path.append(obj1.move)
```

You apparently were hoping for *this* behavior:

```
   obj2.path.append(obj1.move)
```

You will need to use a different index into `obj_list`
in order to locate `obj2`.

---

By default your ctor initializes a node's `path` to `None`.
Better to initialize to an empty list, so subsequent `.append()` will work.

Comment: Thank you, but Im hoping for a obj1.path.append(obj1.move) and obj2.path.append(obj2.move)